# How to parse a deep nested XML in python

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python, and I have a situation

```
<a>
<b>
  <c>
    <d>abcd</d>
       <e>
         <f>pqrs</f></e></d></c></b></a>
```

The algorithm is supposed to be if d has **abcd** , then find f, if f is present, return a true else return a false with **abcd**.

I would be grateful if there are someone can help me figure how to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you read any tutorials how to parse XMLs? Have you tried any of the examples?

Comment: Please inform about python and xml first and take a look at [how to ask a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Where is the relation to AUTOSAR in this question?

Comment: While I feel with you and emphatically see the obvious relation between extremely deeply nested XML documents and AUTOSAR, you should really consider explaining that relation or (because it is not really required for understanding your question) deleting the AUTOSAR tag. You could also add a desired result.

Comment: Hey all, This was a conceptual question, I am a bit new to coding as of whole, but I would try to be more precise.
@Yunnosch : I will form a better version of the question.

Comment: On the side, the reason for three of the closevotes apparently is "Because." Is there any context which makes that a helpful statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive XPath to attempt to find the matching tag and text and then another one to test for the presence of the other tag as follow:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def find_d(root):
    if root.findtext('.//d') == 'abcd':
        return root.find('.//f') is not None
    return False

xml_data = """<a>
<b>
  <c>
    <d>abcd</d>
       <e>
         <f>pqrs</f></e></c></b></a>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
print find_d(root)
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed a command like find text.